# Angular8 How to add string to <head> in index.html

Tags: string, addition, meta-tags, angular8

IN razor format, we can use @Html.Raw to add meta-tags from string, for example, in controller we can write;
Model header = new Model();
header = "`<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\">`";

in Layout Page we can add the above string in `<Head>` section as
 @Html.Raw(Model.header)

How can I do the same in Index.Html in Angular 8 (not using razor). The string "`<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\">`"
is retrieved from DB and need to be appended to "`<Head>`" section in index.html. I do not have control over what will be provided from DB. But whatever will be the value it will be `<Head>` or section related, and may also include `<scripts>`.

Thanks
Found the answer, for someone who is also looking for this solution:

```
let fragment = document.createRange().createContextualFragment("<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\">");
document.head.append(fragment);
```